# How to call Express variable after page load/an event and not before?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I recently started my first frontend project at my place of work. Basically, it's a map of our office with clickable  and popup windows with info about user (who sits at this particular desk) from Mysql database.

Server runs on Node and the problem is with functions that are trying to run before they get the paramete, which is passed after user clicks on certain desk, the URL appends and EJS.

## database.js

```
export async function getUser(place) {
    const [rows] = await pool.query(`
    SELECT *
    FROM users 
    WHERE place = ?
    `, [place])
    return rows [0]
}
```

## app.js

```
app.get("/:place", async (req,res) => {
  const place = req.params.place
  const user = await getUser(place)
  res.render('users.ejs', {user: user})
})
```

## index.ejs

So this is how it works right now: 
user clicks on area with 6A1 href => it appends URL => app.js looks at it, grabs "place" and passes it as a parameter to getUser function => getUser looks inside database and grabs data, passes it to app.hs=> app.js renders "users.ejs" template and sends data (in this example - only "user") to this template.

It works fine, but i want to display it inside a popup on the same page, but, as you can see, script won't work without "place", and it's not there, when you open page (it's just "/"). I tried to use partials on the page (inside simple popup), but since function getUser need parameter "place" it just spits out:

```
ReferenceError: /var/www/html/views/index.ejs:20
    18|     };
    19|     function open_popup() {
    20|         <% -include('users.ejs') %>
    21|         alert('works?')
    22|     }
    23|     </script>

/var/www/html/views/users.ejs:7
    5|         <div class="popup_title">
    6|             <h2>
    7|                 Name: <%= JSON.stringify(user.name) %>
    8|             </h2>
    9|         </div>
   10|         <div class="popup_text">

user is not defined
```

Due to the severe lack of expirience, i can't wrap my head around the sollution. Is there any way to stop functions at app.js file from running (by binding it to eventListener or onClick function - can't find info about how can one put ejs tags inside a tag in index.ejs, or something similar) or maybe my whole struction is only going to work like in an example above and i need to redo the whole thing?

Would really appriciate any and all feedback and possible sollutions, thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at [the documentation](https://ejs.co/). Scroll to the heading marked Docs. Look at the heading marked Example immediately under it. Look at that code example.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is understand how to draw popups. I'd suggest stop using express when trying to understand HTML. Just use a simple file. Figure out how to make the popup work (eg. learn about `element.appendChild()` and `element.innerHTML` and manipulating styles and classes in javascript etc). Generally returning a div is **not** how it works (unless you're doing something with jsx like React or Solid). The simplest old-school way to do popups is to use `display:none` and `display:block` to hide and show the popup etc.